# Operator Error in Revit Statement

Tags: operator-keyword, revit

if (ElementId.op_Inequality(primaryViewId, ElementId.InvalidElementId))

Error: 'Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementId.operator !=(Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementId, Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementId)': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
if (primaryViewId != ElementId.InvalidElementId)
```